# gridview overlap horizontally in pre lollipop device

Tags: android, gridview

I used hacky gridview because i need gridview to wraps content in scrollview so I used custom Gridview from [this site](https://www.jayway.com/2012/10/04/how-to-make-the-height-of-a-gridview-wrap-its-content/) . In preLollipop version everything is ok but in Lollipop there is no border for content of grid view. so I set vertical spacing like below.

```
    <bazit.utils.WrapContentHeightGridView
    android:id="@+id/four_items_gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/home_category_items"
    android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/home_category_items">

</bazit.utils.WrapContentHeightGridView>
```

and using cardview with image in it but after that the cards overlap in pre-lollipop version device. and cardviews shift to right a little.

[overlapping cardviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbXZd.png)

I used margin for cardview but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.
my container view is set RTL(right to left). I change it to LTR and it fixed my problem.